# Wamp or Xampp not running on Zinox laptop windows7 64bit

Tags: xampp, wamp

I am using a Zinox laptop Windows7 professional, service pack1 64-bit. But any of Wamp or Xampp I've installed is working especially Apache Service not running. No matter how I try, installing these service (Apache and MySql) would always fail.

The error message I get sometimes talks of Port 80 and one other port already in use.

Any body already using this same Zinox product should try any of Wamp or Xampp, if it works, please post here.

If anybody knows how to configure/change ports (e.g. letting Wamp or Xampp run on a different port other than Port 80) advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like port 80 is reserved by other application!

You can try changing port, look into Apache configuration **httpd.conf** assign a new port and restart apache

```
Listen 81
```

Access it like this localhost:81

Comment: Tnx, will try n get back pls.